# MySQL | Count rows IF 0 then return

Tags: javascript, mysql, count, rows

I want to create a function which check if there a any locations within a certain distance from a waypoint. the function to calculate the distance is already working. I start with the query shown below.

```
select loc_id from wp where calc_distance(52.15819, 6.40726, wp.lat, wp.lon) <100;
```

This query wil result in several rows, the next step would be to count the amount of rows, why won't the query below result in a number?

```
select count(loc_id from wp where calc_distance(52.15819, 6.40726, wp.lat, wp.lon) <100);
```

Any thoughts?

Small side question: What wuold be perferred:

1. Ccreate this function within MySQL and only call it from within a javascript file.
2. Create this function within my js file and only read the mySQL table when the javascript function is called.

TIA

ABBOV

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error is all. You need a closing parenthesis after `loc_id`

```
select count(loc_id) from wp where calc_distance(52.15819, 6.40726, wp.lat, wp.lon) <100;
```

Comment: Sometimes it's just that simple, maybe I was just looking at a screen to long. Thanks. :)